# IMacros Sequential run

Tags: imacros, sequential

Hi guys I would really appreciate help with this issue I'm using the I-Macros free ad on for Firefox and chrome. I've created several Macros for a website regression, but I can't seem to make them run sequentially for example i have

Test case 1
Test case 2
Test case 3

and what I want is when test case #1 finishes it continues with #2 then #3 etc

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you have macros like "Testcase1.iim" "Testcase2.iim" etc?
To run them in any order you want you could use [iimPlay](http://wiki.imacros.net/iimPlay()) in a JavaScript macro, at least in Firefox. It would look something like this

```
iimPlay("Testcase1.iim");
iimPlay("Testcase2.iim");
[..]
```

As soon as Testcase1 is done it play Testcase2 and so on.